# Auto request again after returned false

Tags: swift, timer, alamofire

I've got some idea about auto request again after 2 second if the returned data status is 201.
From the beginning, i'm using Timer to delay it and make a request once. But my request dind't run again. Any solution? Thanks. Here is my code:

```
 Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval:2, repeats: true) { timer in
                        let url = "exampleweb.com" // This will be your link
                        let parameters: Parameters = ["User_type": type, "User_name": name, "User_email": email, "User_contact": contact, "User_password": password, "from_referral": referral]      //This will be your parameter

                        Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: parameters).responseJSON { response in
                            print(response)
                            if response.status = 200 {
                                //Do something when success
                            }else
                            if response.status = 201 {
                                //Do something when failed
                            }
                            
                        }
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Doing network requests on timer is a bad idea. Use `DispatchQueue.asyncAfter` instead:

```
func runRequest() {
    Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: parameters).responseJSON { response in
        print(response)
        if response.status = 200 {
            //Do something when success
        }else
        if response.status = 201 {
            // Repeat request after 2 sec:
            DispatchQueue.global().asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2.0) {
                self.runRequest()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I use `global` queue, which you may want to fine tune it to certain `qos` level. For example `userInitiated` is request is important, and `background` if it has a medium/low priority. Not recommending to run this on `DispatchQueue.main` though.

Answer (score -1):

I have slightly modified your code.
Timer will stop when response.status = 200.
You can also use recursion to handle this problem.

```
let timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval:2, repeats: true) { timer in
                    let url = "exampleweb.com" // This will be your link
                    let parameters: Parameters = ["User_type": type, "User_name": name, "User_email": email, "User_contact": contact, "User_password": password, "from_referral": referral]      //This will be your parameter

                    Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: parameters).responseJSON { response in
                        print(response)
                        if response.status = 200 {
                            timer.invalidate()
                            //Do something when success
                        }else
                        if response.status = 201 {
                            //Do something when failed
                        }
                        
                    }
                }
```

Comment: timer with non-UI operations is always a bad idea

Comment: Thank I don't know that.

Answer (score -1):

It's better to schedule network call using `.asyncAfter` on some queue with specified `DispatchQoS` (maybe on your special queue, dedicated to performing network requests)

Also it's better to use recursion inside function:

```swift
func send(request: Request, retryCount: Int) {

    Alamofire.request(...).responseJSON { response in

        switch response.status {
        case 200:
            // handle success
        case 201:
            if retryCount > 0 {
                send(request: request, retryCount: retryCount - 1)
            } else {
                // handle response
            }
        default:
            // handle other scenarios
    }
}
```